# Get-Help shows different outputs on different systems

Tags: powershell

When I use the following cmdlet:

```
Get-Help Get-ADUser -Parameter identity
```

On Windows 7 with RSAT installed connecting to Windows Server 2012 R2, I get the following output:

```
-Identity <ADUser>
Specifies an Active Directory user object by providing one of the following property values. The identifier in
parentheses is the LDAP display name for the attribute.

  Distinguished Name
    Example:  CN=SaraDavis,CN=Europe,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com
  GUID (objectGUID)
    Example: 599c3d2e-f72d-4d20-8a88-030d99495f20
  Security Identifier (objectSid)
    Example: S-1-5-21-3165297888-301567370-576410423-1103
  SAM account name  (sAMAccountName)
    Example: saradavis

The cmdlet searches the default naming context or partition to find the object. If two or more objects are found
the cmdlet returns a non-terminating error.

This parameter can also get this object through the pipeline or you can set this parameter to an object instance

This example shows how to set the parameter to a distinguished name.
  -Identity  "CN=SaraDavis,CN=Europe,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com"

This example shows how to set this parameter to a user object instance named "userInstance".
  -Identity   $userInstance

Required?                    true
Position?                    1
Default value
Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

However when I use it on a Windows Server 2012 R2 or 2016 with WMF 5.1 installed I only get the following:

```
-Identity <ADUser>
Required?                    true
Position?                    1
Default value
Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's just a guess from me... try the parameter -full

Comment: Thanks, tried that, throws an invalid argument error, also tried -detailed. Thank you for trying though. Much appreciated.

Comment: You may need an administrator to run `Update-Help`  on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-ADUser command comes from a 'system module' that can be different from an OS to an other even with the same version of WMF and even if the version number shown by 'Get-Command Get-ADUser' is the same (1.0.0.0) ... so help content may be different too.

By the way, I get this result on my Windows 2012 R2 with WMF 5.1

```
-Identity <ADUser>
    Specifies an Active Directory user object by providing one of the following property values. The identifier in
    parentheses is the LDAP display name for the attribute. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

    -- A Distinguished Name
    -- A GUID (objectGUID)
    -- A Security Identifier (objectSid)
    -- A SAM Account Name (sAMAccountName)

    The cmdlet searches the default naming context or partition to find the object. If two or more objects are found,
    the cmdlet returns a non-terminating error.

    This parameter can also get this object through the pipeline or you can set this parameter to an object instance.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

You may try ***Update-Help*** to download latest PowerShell help files (if your server is connected to Internet...).